# clang static analyzer reports memory leak using unique_ptr. False positive?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, clang-static-analyzer

I have a class that uses `std::unique_ptr` for memory, but clang-check reports a "potential leak of memory". I can't figure out why and if I'm doing something wrong or if this is a false positive. Running valgrind finds no leaks.

The code (see below) is nested several layers, I could not reduce it further while still triggering the leak check.

Essentially, I have a class `Func` that acts similar to `std::function`, i.e. it is a type-erased wrapper for any functor object that provides the (duck-typed) interface `double operator()(double x) const`. It wraps this object using a `std::unique_ptr<Callable>`, where `Callable` is the interface for said method (and has a virtual destructor and clone for polymorphic copy). Type erasure is implemeted using the class template `CallableImpl` that has the actual functor as a member.
Thus, objects of type `Func` have value semantics and should be copy-able in any way without leaking memory, due to `unique_ptr` and the virtual dtor.

I then have several auxiliary classes that just exercise this, wrapped into each other, to trigger the leak check.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

// Interface for a functor object providing method double operator()(double)
class Callable
{
public:
    using FuncPtr = std::unique_ptr<Callable>;

    Callable() = default;
    virtual ~Callable() = default;

    // Call function
    virtual double operator()(double x) const = 0;

    // Polymorphic copy constructor
    virtual FuncPtr clone() const = 0;
};

// Generic implementation that equips Functor with the Callable interface
// as long as it provides the required (non-virtual) method.
template <typename Functor>
class CallableImpl : public Callable
{
public:
    CallableImpl(Functor f) : f(std::move(f)) {}
    CallableImpl(const CallableImpl&) = default;
    CallableImpl(CallableImpl&&) = default;


    double operator()(double x) const override
    {
        return f(x);
    }

    FuncPtr clone() const override
    {
        return std::make_unique<CallableImpl>(*this);
    }

private:
    Functor f;
};

// Type-erased functor
class Func final
{
    using FuncPtr = Callable::FuncPtr;
    FuncPtr func;

public:
    // Type erasing constructor for generic callables
    template <typename T>
    Func(T callable)
        : func(std::make_unique<CallableImpl<T>>(std::move(callable)))
    {
    }

    // Copy constructor
    Func(const Func& rhs) : func(rhs.func->clone()) {}
    // Move constructor
    Func(Func&&) = default;

    // Copy assignment
    Func& operator=(const Func& rhs)
    {
        func = rhs.func->clone();
        return *this;
    }
    // Move assignment
    Func& operator=(Func&& rhs) = default;

    // Call function
    double operator()(double x) const
    {
        return (*func)(x);
    }
};

// A class that implements the Callable concept of Func, including some state
class AddConstant
{
public:
    AddConstant(double c) : c(c) {}
    double operator()(double  x) const { return x + c; }

private:
    double c;
};

// A class that takes a Func and trivially executes
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(Func f) : f(std::move(f)) {}
    double operator()(double x) const { return f(x); }

private:
    Func f;
};

// Some additional wrapping that should do nothing but is needed for the
// leak warning to trigger.
struct WrapFoo
{
    Foo f;
};

// This is also needed tp trigger the warning for some reason, although directly
// using the expression herein works fine.
WrapFoo makeWrapFoo(const Func& fa)
{
    return {Foo(fa)};
}


int main()
{
    AddConstant callable = AddConstant(3);    // ok
    Func func = {AddConstant(3)};             // ok
    Foo foo = {func};                         // ok
    Foo copy = foo;                           // ok
    WrapFoo wrappedFoo = WrapFoo{Foo(func)};  // ok
    WrapFoo wrapper = makeWrapFoo(func);      // Potential leak of memory

    std::cout << "f(42): " << wrapper.f(42)
              << ", direct: " << callable(42) << std::endl;
}
```

The clang analyzer (clang version 12.0.0) output is:

```
$ /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/12.0.0/libexec/c++-analyzer -std=c++17 main.cpp

main.cpp:124:5: warning: Potential leak of memory pointed to by field '__value_' [cplusplus.NewDeleteLeaks]
    WrapFoo wrapper = makeWrapFoo(func);      // Potential leak of memory
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

This is on libc++. On a linux machine whith libstdc++ I also get the warning.

Comment: Can't say I read it all, but `-fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined` didn't catch anything.

Comment: Did you try running this under valgrind?  The code is pretty complex, maybe you fooled the analyser.

Comment: Show the command line for the clang static analyzer.

Comment: I ran clang-sa version 8.0.0 on the above code and it didn't detect any problems; perhaps you are seeing a clang-sa bug that was fixed in a newer version?  (if you want you can clone the clang-sa code from github and compile from the latest codebase there to see if it makes a difference)

Comment: ¿Are you sure that this example is a minimal example?

Comment: @PaulSanders as mentioned, valgrind didn't find anything.

Comment: @user7860670 it may not be minimal, but I couldn't find a way to reduce it while still triggering the warning. Most curiously, even the line `WrapFoo wrappedFoo = WrapFoo{Foo(func)};`, which should do the same as the following line, doesn't trigger.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that.  Looks like you fooled the analyser.  I believe it is 'experimental'.

Comment: Could be this bug perhaps? https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38176